# Does IsoStoreSpy work on any device or only developer unlocked ones?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I was wondering whether IsoStoreSpy (https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) works with non-developer-unlocked devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's even more restrictive than that -- the feature only works for side-loaded apps, which require dev-unlocked phones. If you're trying to extract the contents of an app's storage (where the app came from the Store) there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter has said, in answer to your question, due to the nature of the IsoStoreSpy software, you will need to have a developer unlocked phone as it can only read data from apps that have been side-loaded/debugged on the device.